# Use Two Foreach For Two Tables On One View In Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am using Codeigniter, I am creating a function that replaces text based on the values in a table using 2 variables taken from two Foreach functions, the following is an example of code that I have written but it doesn't seem to work as it should

**Table "Claim" & 'Claim_process" Structure**

```
id_claim | artist_name | claim_date | claim_amount | status
```

**Model**

```
//ADMIN_CLAIM

 function Tampil_claim_admin(){
  return $this->db->get('claim');
 }
  function Input_claim($data,$table){
  $this->db->insert($table,$data);
 }
 
 function edit_claim($where,$table){  
  return $this->db->get_where($table,$where);
 }

 function update_claim($where,$data,$table){
  $this->db->where($where);
  $this->db->update($table,$data);
 }

 function delete_claim($where,$table){
  $this->db->where($where);
  $this->db->delete($table);
 } 

  //ADMIN_CLAIM_PROCESS

 function Tampil_claim_admin_process(){
  return $this->db->get('claim_process');
 }
  function Input_claim_process($data,$table){
  $this->db->insert($table,$data);
 }
 
 function edit_claim_process($where,$table){  
  return $this->db->get_where($table,$where);
 }

 function update_claim_process($where,$data,$table){
  $this->db->where($where);
  $this->db->update($table,$data);
 }

 function delete_claim_process($where,$table){
  $this->db->where($where);
  $this->db->delete($table);
 }
```

**Controller**

```
function index(){
$data['claim'] = $this->m_admin_data->Tampil_claim_admin()->result();
$data['claim_process'] = $this->m_admin_data->Tampil_claim_admin_process()->result();
$this->load->view('admin/v_admin_claim',$data);
}
```

**View**

```
<tr>
<td>MSC-CLAIM- <?php foreach ($claim as $data):
endforeach;

foreach ($claim_process as $data):
endforeach;

echo $data->id_claim; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $data->artist_name; ?></td>

<td><?php echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($data->claim_date)); ?></td>  
                                                 

<td>$ <?php echo $data->claim_amount; ?></td>  


<td><?php if ($data->status = 'On Process') { ?>
<?php echo anchor('Admin_claim/edit_claim_process/' . $data->id_claim, 'Process'); ?>  
<?php else { ?>

<span class="label label-primary"> <?php echo "Sudah di Selesai"; ?> </span>

<?php } ?></td>
```

Comment: not sure what it is what you want to do, nor where you're stuck. What is the text you want to replace, and what do you want it replaced with?

Comment: First Point: Your foreach loops do nothing! There is no code in them. 
Second Point: Why have you reversed the order of the parameters in your model methods to those in the db methods. This seems counter intuitive and confusing. Third Point: Why Are you mixing Case with your model method names. Is there a reason for that? I.E. why is Tampil_claim_admin() not tampil_claim_admin() in keeping with the other method naming convention you have used? Fourth Point: How are you matching the claims with the claims process?